Error relating to start tags and end tags in .NET MAUI
I'm trying to create an Entry element in .NET MAUI, this is the code for the entire page:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.MainPage">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="120, Auto, *"
          Padding="10">

        <Entry Placeholder="Search..."/>

    </Grid>
    

</ContentPage>

However it keeps throwing this error:
"Error The 'Entry' start tag on line 9 position 10 does not match the 'Grid' end tag. Line 11, position 7.
It seems like it wants for the Entry to be closed with the Grid? But I don't see how this makes sense.
I've tried changing the:
<Entry Placeholder="Search..."/>

to a:
<Entry Placeholder="Search...">
</Entry>

But the exact same error also happens.
Thanks in advance.

Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this problem. You can check if the symbol / is in the correct format.

Also check for hidden characters

Tried deleting and rewriting a few times, it's weird because other elements like Images or Labels work just fine but any Entry seems to give this error.

Hi @ExitThe, could you please post a Minimal, Reproducible Example here so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?
